# Image of measurable set under continuous inverse function is always measurable?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on a set $E$.  Is it always true that $f^{-1}(A)$ is always measurable if $A$ is measurable?

Is this correct?

Comment: What $\sigma$-algebras? It's true for the Borel $\sigma$-algebras, but for unrelated $\sigma$-algebras, there's no reason for a continuous function to be measurable.

Comment: Would you please give me the proof?

Comment: The usual counterexample is to take the [Cantor Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) $\phi$ and define $\psi(x)=x+\phi(x)$. $\psi$ is one-to-one and maps the measure-zero Cantor set onto a set $A$ of positive measure. Now consider the inverse of $\psi$ and a non-measurable subset of $A$.  c.f. Gelbaum and Olmsted, *Counterexamples in Analysis*, example 8.16.

Comment: The above of course is meant for the case where "measurable" means "Lebesgue measurable".

Comment: Hey David,thank you. I know we should use that Cantor function. Actually I searched that book but I can't find example 8.16.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pre-image of a measurable set A is always measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207040/pre-image-of-a-measurable-set-a-is-always-measurable)

Answer (score 11):

Negative answer by David Mitra.

Take the [Cantor Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) $\phi$ and define $\psi(x)=x+\phi (x)$. The function $\psi$  is one-to-one and maps the measure-zero Cantor set onto a set $E$ of positive measure. Let $B$ be a  non-measurable subset of $E$. (Every set of positive measure contains a nonmeasurable  set.) The set $A=\psi^{-1}(B)$ is a subset of the Cantor set, and is therefore measurable. This gives a counterexample ($ f=\psi^{-1}$).

c.f. Gelbaum and Olmsted, Counterexamples in Analysis, example 8.16.