# If $f$ measurable and $E$ measurable, does $f(E)$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb R^d\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ measurable and $E\subset \mathbb R^d$ measurable, does $f(E)$ measurable ?

I proved that if $f$ is a bijection, it hold since if $g$ is the reciprocal of $f$, then $g$ is mesurable and $f(E)=g^{-1}(E)$, therefore $f(E)$ is measurable.

Comment: $ f (E) = E $ does not follow from $ f $ being a bijection.

Comment: Please look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530280/image-of-measurable-set-under-continuous-inverse-function-is-always-measurable