# Why does this function preserve measure of null sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259166/fx-y-considered-as-a-function-of-x-y-in-mathbbr2n-is-measurable-if) question, one of the answers claimed that the function $f: \mathbb{R}^{2n} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y) = x-y$ pulls back Lebesgue null sets to null sets, that is, $f^{-1}(N)$ is a null set for any null set $N$ and mentions it can be proved using Fubini's theorem, but gives no proof of this.

Could someone elaborate on why this must be true?

Comment: yes, I will edit this to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be null.
$$\begin{align*}
\lambda^2(S) &= \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \chi_{f^{-1}[S]} d\lambda^2
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} [x - y \in S] dx\,dy \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_{S + y}(x) dx\,dy \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} 0\,dy  = 0
\end{align*}$$
where $[\cdot]$ is the Iverson bracket. Notice that $x - y \in S \iff x \in S + y$. Since Lebesgue measure is invariant under translations, $S + y$ is again null.

Comment: this clears it up, thank you!